# Why `os.getpid` returns a negative pid on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, pid, spawn

I remember not long time ago, someone asked about Windows having negative PIDs here, I just can't find that question anymore. In all cases, I've seen some code from Learning Python 4th Edition which contains negative process ids, so let's see the code first:

```
#spawnv.py
import os, sys

for i in range(10):
    if sys.platform[:3] == 'win':
        pypath = sys.executable
        os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT, pypath, ('python', 'child.py', str(i)))
    else:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid != 0:
            print('Process %d spawned' % pid)
        else:
            os.execlp('python3', 'python3', 'child.py', str(i))
print('Main process exiting.')
```

---

```
#child.py
import os, sys
print('Hello from child', os.getpid(), sys.argv[1])
```

And the output as mention in the book:

```
Hello from child −583587 0
Hello from child −558199 2
Hello from child −586755 1
Hello from child −562171 3
Main process exiting.
Hello from child −581867 6
Hello from child −588651 5
Hello from child −568247 4
Hello from child −563527 7
Hello from child −543163 9
Hello from child −587083 8
```

I ran the exact same code on Windows 7, all the spawned processes have positive PIDs. The fact that `P_NOWAIT` flag is used for `spawnv` makes it more baffling. `P_WAIT` can return  a negative status code: `-SIGNAL`.

Is it a typo or Windows can have negative PIDs?

Comment: In my understanding negative PIDs are often used to indicate, that this is not a real process but a `pseudo process`/`thread` (https://prodlife.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/fork-on-windows/). So maybe this is part of the solution.

Comment: @FlashTek Perhaps this is how it was implemented previously, using threads. But using `exec` on a thread will replace the whole process in Linux.

Comment: You're not printing or using the value returned by `os.spawnv`. The printed PID is from calling `os.getpid()` in the child process. Python does use a signed value here, i.e. the C implementation calls `PyLong_FromLong(getpid())`, but to get -583587 the unsigned PID would have to be 4294383709. The large magnitude of this number strains credibility. Also it's not a multiple of 4 as one would expect for a process or thread ID on Windows (an implementation detail, but a stable one).

Comment: I don't see anything surprising here.  You're running a newer version of Python than the one in the book (which is nearly 8 years old, after all) and it just happens to implement fork/exec differently.  The author might even have been running the Cygwin build of Python rather than the native Windows build.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, the negative PIDs are from `os.getpid()`, for which POSIX `getpid` is defined to return a `pid_t`, a [signed integer value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12). In principle it's possible for `getpid()` to return a negative value if the PID of the current process is greater than 0x7FFFFFFF. That's improbable in NT -- but maybe it's more likely in Windows 9x? I think it's more likely that this is either a typo or a fabricated result.

Comment: @eryksun You're right. I have to change the title of the question. It's getpid which returns the negative pid. Let's assume this is a typo in the book for now.

Comment: The author may have been using Windows 9x. I don't recall what a typical PID value was in that case. It may have simply been a kernel address above 0x7FFFFFFF, in which case the negative values are correct.

Comment: @eryksun The author mentioned using Windows 7 in some paragraphs. The book is not that old, this is the 4th Edition.

Comment: It may be an old example from the 1st edition.

Comment: @eryksun could be.

Answer (score 1):

The `PID` on Windows is always greater `0` and will be stored as a `uint32` according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx). Therefore, a real `PID` which is negative does not make much sense.